# Moving data to another sheet and specific cell not working as anticipated

Tags: vba, excel

I have my data all on one sheet ("PBT"). There are different ranges of data that need to go to different sheets. My current code will move the data to the sheet I want; however, it starts putting the data into A4 and then puts the next row into A3, A2, and then deletes anything else. I'd like it to go down from A4 and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is the code:

```
Sub Move_Data()
'Moves data to set worksheets
Dim Firstrow As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim Lrow As Long
Dim CalcMode As Long
Dim ViewMode As Long

With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

'We use the ActiveSheet but you can replace this with
'Sheets("MySheet")if you want
With Sheets("PBT")

    'We select the sheet so we can change the window view
    .Select

    'If you are in Page Break Preview Or Page Layout view go
    'back to normal view, we do this for speed
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

    'Turn off Page Breaks, we do this for speed
    .DisplayPageBreaks = False

    'Set the first and last row to loop through
    Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
    Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

    'We loop from Lastrow to Firstrow (bottom to top)
    For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1

        'We check the values in the A column in this example
        With .Cells(Lrow, "A")

            If Not IsError(.Value) Then

                If Right(.Value, 7) >= 30001 And Right(.Value, 7) <= 32500 Then .EntireRow.Cut Sheets("WTH").Range("A4").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                'in Column A, case sensitive.

            End If

        End With

    Next Lrow

End With

ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = CalcMode
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This.  Your For Loop was going backwards from the last row to the first row.  I took out the Step - 1 to make it increase instead of decrease and I flipped around the Firstrow and Lastrow so it starts on the first row and stops on the Lastrow.

Initial State of Sheet1:  (Sheet2 is blank)

[image]

State of Sheet1 after code:
[image]

State of Sheet2 after code:
[image]

```
 Sub Move_Data()
'Moves data to set worksheets
Dim Firstrow As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim Lrow As Long
Dim CalcMode As Long
Dim ViewMode As Long
Dim num_of_entries As Integer
With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With
num_of_entries = 0
'We use the ActiveSheet but you can replace this with
'Sheets("MySheet")if you want
With Sheets("Sheet1")

    'We select the sheet so we can change the window view


    'If you are in Page Break Preview Or Page Layout view go
    'back to normal view, we do this for speed

    'Turn off Page Breaks, we do this for speed

    'Set the first and last row to loop through
    Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
    Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

    'We loop from Lastrow to Firstrow (bottom to top)
    For Lrow = Firstrow To Lastrow

        'We check the values in the A column in this example
        With .Cells(Lrow, "A")

            If Not IsError(.Value) Then

                If Right(.Value, 7) >= 30001 And Right(.Value, 7) <= 32500 Then

                    .EntireRow.Cut Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A4").Offset(num_of_entries)
                    num_of_entries = num_of_entries + 1
                'in Column A, case sensitive.
                End If
            End If

        End With

    Next Lrow

End With

'ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = CalcMode
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The reason the OP was going backward is the op is cutting whole rows, shifting the cells up.  By going forward rows will be skipped.  if lrow = 14 and it is cut what is row 15 becomes row 14 and the next loop lrow is 15 and it goes to what was row 16 and now 15, so what was in row 15 before the cut gets skipped.  Not to mention it continues through empty rows at the end.

Comment: Yaegz - Scott appears to be correct. Taking out the Step -1 causes nothing to move over to the other sheet at all actually.

I see how my current code is causing it to go backwards and when I use .End(xlDown).Offset(-1) it works properly; however, this causes all of the data  to generate at the very end of the allowable rows rather than in A4 as I'd like - not sure how to fix that issue. I'm still new to VBA so I apologize if these are easy questions!

Comment: @beckd40 I edited my code and answer.  Are my pictures what you are looking for?  Should I be deleting blank rows on the first sheet after I paste the information?

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much. At this point, I don't need to delete blank rows. I've been racking my brain on this issue for awhile now and I'm glad it was such an easy fix.

Comment: @beckd40 np, I am happy to help.  Be aware that this code will not necessarily work if there is already information in the second sheet.  I would write a quick Do While loop to determine how many rows are already populated and set num_of_entries = to the number of rows in the do while loop.  I can help with this if you need it.  Do not forget to accept this answer and to throw me an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version of the code that could solve some issues.
1. Go forward through the loop so you know where the write the values in the other sheet
2. By going forward you have to make sure to stay on the same row whenever you cut a row out, and not to go beyond the end of the now shorter list.

I marked the lines I changed with ***** in the comments.

```
Sub Move_Data()
'Moves data to set worksheets
'**** We dont need Firstrow anymore
'**** Dim Firstrow As Long
'**** Use Targetrow for driving where the move should be to
Dim TargetRow as Long
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim Lrow As Long
Dim CalcMode As Long
Dim ViewMode As Long

With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

'We use the ActiveSheet but you can replace this with
'Sheets("MySheet")if you want
With Sheets("PBT")

    'We select the sheet so we can change the window view
    .Select

    'If you are in Page Break Preview Or Page Layout view go
    'back to normal view, we do this for speed
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

    'Turn off Page Breaks, we do this for speed
    .DisplayPageBreaks = False

    'Set the first and last row to loop through
    '**** Assign to Lrow as we will use While loop
    Lrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
    Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
    '**** New variable for reference in target sheet
    TargetRow = 5

    ' ***** We loop forward now
    Do While Lrow <= Lastrow
        'We check the values in the A column in this example
        With .Cells(Lrow, "A")
            If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If Right(.Value, 7) >= 30001 And Right(.Value, 7) <= 32500 Then
                   'in Column A, case sensitive.
                   ' **** Use Target Row to determine destination range
                   .EntireRow.Cut Sheets("WTH").Range("A" & TargetRow)
                   ' **** increment the target row for next move.
                   TargetRow = TargetRow + 1
                   ' **** As we removed one row, our last row is one less now
                   Lastrow = Lastrow - 1
                   ' *** Counter the increment to the row, as we have the new
                   ' *** row already at the position where we cut one away
                   Lrow = Lrow - 1
                End If
            End If
            ' **** Increment
            Lrow = Lrow + 1
        End With
    '****
    Loop

End With

ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = CalcMode
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this code as well but it was only dropping in the first row

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to increment the TargetRow inside the deepest If. I adapt the code. Let me know if it works now.